# Using mapping tool when source and destination differ in shape and names

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I need to map an object to another where source and destination types differs quite a lot in both shape and member names. Here's an example of a mapping:

```
var source = new Source();
var dest = new Destination
{
    PropertyA = new SomeTypeA
        {
            PropertyB = new SomeTypeB
                {
                    DestinationProperty = source.SourceProperty
                }
        }
};
```

In this example the SomeTypeA doesn't have any corresponding type in the Source type and the SomeTypeB only has one property that has a corresponding property in Source namely SourceProperty. So there's quite some differences in the source and destination objects.

My question is: is there any mapping tool like AutoMapper that is a good fit for mapping here or is manual mapping more appropriate?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use automapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper is a conventional-based mapped. Hence, everything, that beyond the conventions, must be tuned manually. If the most part of mapping is covered by conventions, then there's nothing wrong with some special setups:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .AfterMap((s, d) => d.PropertyA.PropertyB.DestinationProperty = s.SourceProperty);
```

Of course, this makes sense, if you don't need to do mappings this way for each property in the destination type. In this case custom mapping can be less evil, than using any mapping tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoMapper and setup mappings for each property manually. But this can be clumsy and is not ideal if your objects are very complex. So it depends. :-)

An alternative approach could be to do it manually using extension methods on the types you want to convert to and from:

```
public static Destination ToDestination(this Source source) {
 // convert here
}
```